# Name of the imported function in `_ast`

Tags: python, import, abstract-syntax-tree

I'm using `_ast` to do some code analysis and have run into an issue with getting the name of an imported function.
Suppose my code file (`code.py`) looks like this:

```
import somemod
def foo():
    somemod.bar()
```

When I get the ast for this file with `root = compile(open('codefile.py').read(), 'codefile.py', 'exec', _ast.PyCF_ONLY_AST)`, I can get the line calling `somemod.bar` like this:

```
root.body[1].body[0]
```

This is an `_ast.Expr` node.
I then expect to be able to get `somemod.bar` by looking into this node. However, when I look at `root.body[1].body[0].value.func.value.id`, I get `somemod`. As far as I can tell, I can't find a way to get `bar` or `somemod.bar`

What am I missing? How can I get at the `bar`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's in `value.func.attr`:

```
>>> root = compile(open('codefile.py').read(), 'codefile.py', 'exec', _ast.PyCF_ONLY_AST)
>>> root.body[1].body[0].value.func
<_ast.Attribute object at 0x9703acc>
>>> f = root.body[1].body[0].value.func
>>> vars(f)
{'col_offset': 4, 'ctx': <_ast.Load object at 0xb6e2c6cc>, 'attr': 'bar', 'value': <_ast.Name object at 0x9703a8c>, 'lineno': 3}
>>> f.attr
'bar'
>>> f.value.id
'somemod'
```

Comment: Ahh! thank you so much. This was driving me crazy. PS: Thanks for `vars` (didn't know about that before)